# How to add space for xticklabels in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

all, I'm using Matplotlib to plot a polarbar. But the ticks are overlapped.

Does anybody know how to avoid this? Thanks!

```
from pylab      import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cf.plot    import BoundaryNorm,getBoundCmap
from matplotlib import colors

fig     = figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax      = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)

N = 8
theta   = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/N)
radii   = ones((1,N)).squeeze()
width   = 2*np.pi/N
bars    = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.6)

listBnd = [0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24]

mcolors = plt.cm.Spectral(linspace(0,1,N))
cmap    = colors.ListedColormap(mcolors)

for r,bar in zip(arange(1,N+1), bars):
    bar.set_facecolor(cmap(r-1))

xlabels = array([0,21,18,15,12,9,6,3])
ax.xaxis.labelpad=50
ax.set_xticks(theta)
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels,rotation=270,fontsize='60')
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5,-0.5)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
grid([])

show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, let's clean up your code a bit.  You have a lot of things that don't make sense.  (For example, why generate a list of colors from the colormap, then create another colormap, then get the colors you originally generated from the other colormap?)

In addition, you're setting a lot of parameters that probably don't do what you think they do. (For example, the `labelpad` for an axis controls the padding for the axis label (e.g. xlabel), not for the ticks.)

With that in mind, your code might look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

N = 8
theta = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/N)
radii = np.ones(N)
width = 2 * np.pi / N
bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.6)

colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, N))

for color, bar in zip(colors, bars):
    bar.set_facecolor(color)

xlabels = np.array([0,21,18,15,12,9,6,3])
ax.set_xticks(theta)
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, rotation=270, fontsize=60)

ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.grid(False)

plt.show()
```

Which generates a figure similar to the following:

[image]

---

Basically, you want to use the `frac` kwarg to `ax.set_thetagrids` to change the radial position of the theta tick labels.  (This is a bit hidden, but it's the easiest way to do it.)

In addition, I'm using `fig.tight_layout` to resize things so that the tick labels don't wind up outside of the figure boundaries.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

N = 8
theta = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/N)
radii = np.ones(N)
width = 2 * np.pi / N
bars = ax.bar(theta, radii, width=width, bottom=0.6)

colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, N))

for color, bar in zip(colors, bars):
    bar.set_facecolor(color)

xlabels = np.array([0,21,18,15,12,9,6,3])
ax.set_thetagrids(np.degrees(theta), xlabels, frac=1.2, 
                  rotation=270, fontsize=60)

ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.grid(False)

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Joe, Thank you so much for your big help!!